# How do I read data from large .h5 dataset in batches, preprocess with ImageDataGenerator & model.fit, all without running out of memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hdf5, h5py

**Summary:** Running out of memory when attempting to handle large dataset with TF/Keras.  I know batch processing is a major component to the solution...just don't understand how to implement.

**Question: How do I read in data from an extremely large .h5 dataset in batches, standardize/remove the mean, and then split the data, all without running out of memory?**

**Context:** Building a workflow to investigate unsupervised deep embedded clustering (DEC) of naturally occurring seismic signals.  This problem is specifically within the pre-processing of the data, i.e., preparing the data for training/validating an autoencoder/decoder.

**The Data:** ~6e6 spectrograms of seismic detections from an array.
Dimensions: (m,n,o) = (6e6, 66, 301) = (samples, freq_bins, time_bins).
The data is stored in a .h5 file under one dataset. 
The .h5 file takes up ~1 TB on disk.

**The Hardware:** Dual Intel Xeon E5-2683 v4 2.1 GHz, 40MB cache, 16 cores, 2 Titan GPU, 528GB RAM

**Current Procedure for Pre-processing:**
1. Assemble a numpy array, X, consisting of M spectrograms by choosing M random indices, sorted in increasing order, and slicing the .h5 dataset iteratively.  (Aside: the fastest approach here was to save the .h5 dataset with chunks optimized for later reading, and to then use a simple "for" loop to access the data.  Fancy indexing and "read_direct" took substantially longer to traverse the dataset.)
2. Trim unnecessary data from X (freq and time bin values, and final 46 time bins of data) and add 4th axis, "p", as the "amplitude bin." Final shape: (m,n,o,p) = (M,64,256,1).
3. Remove mean and standardize the data.
4. Split X into training/validation sets.

```
# Define sample size:
M = int(1e6)
# Load spectrograms into X:
with h5py.File(train_dataname, 'r') as f:
    DataSpec = '/30sec/Spectrogram'
    dset = f[DataSpec]
    m, n, o = dset.shape
    index = sorted(np.random.choice(m, size=M, replace=False))
    X = np.empty([M, n, o])
    for i in range(M):
        X[i,:,:] = dset[index[i],:,:]

# Remove the frequency and time vectors from the data, trim time bins to len=256:
X = X[:,1:-1,1:256]

# Add amplitude dimension:
X = X[..., np.newaxis]
m, n, o, p = X.shape

# Remove mean & standardize data:
datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    samplewise_center=True,
    samplewise_std_normalization=True)
datagen.fit(X)
X = datagen.standardize(X)

# Split data into training/validation:
X_train, X_val = train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=812)

# Free up memory:
del X
```

**The Problem in Detail:**
When M ~ 1e6, X takes up approximately 30% of RAM (total RAM is 528GB).  Running the code above produces the memory error below.  It's no surprise I run out of memory, given the operation is copying the entire array...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-fb00ad200706> in <module>
----> 1 datagen.fit(X)

~/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/AEC-DEC/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py in fit(self, x, augment, rounds, seed)
    943             np.random.seed(seed)
    944 
--> 945         x = np.copy(x)
    946         if augment:
    947             ax = np.zeros(

~/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/AEC-DEC/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in copy(a, order)
    790 
    791     """
--> 792     return array(a, order=order, copy=True)
    793 
    794 # Basic operations

MemoryError:
```

**What I'm Trying To Do (and need your help!):**
I know my solution lies with batch processing, but I'm uncertain how to implement it, and also how to pair it with an efficient way to read in .h5 without having to read in M spectrograms into an array, then batch process.  I've identified the model.fit_generator approach, which now seems deprecated in favor of model.fit; and I've read about hdf5matrix utility.  **Stated in a question: How do I read in data from an extremely large .h5 dataset in batches, standardize/remove the mean, and then split the data, all without running out of memory?**

As much time as I've spent trying to figure this out, I'm not clear on how to put all the pieces together, which is why I'm looking for some considered guidance to nudge me in the right direction.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you install h5.py?

Comment: Yes; h5py, numpy, and the required keras/tf modules are imported but not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to avoid processes that double the memory footprint of `X`. (I know, that's stating the obvious). It's a BIG array, and you double the memory needed with `X = X[:,1:-1,1:256]` (and maybe with `X = X[..., np.newaxis]`).
They key is to allocate `X` in the final desired size/shape (to avoid copies). Then modify your logic to load the data  from `dset` (`f['/30sec/Spectrogram']`) into an intermediate array (`ds_arr` below), modify as needed, then load into `X`.

I put together an alternative procedure. This may not be the most computationally efficient, but avoids copies of `X`.

```
# Define sample size:
M = int(1e6)
# Load spectrograms into X:
with h5py.File(train_dataname, 'r') as f:
    DataSpec = '/30sec/Spectrogram'
    dset = f[DataSpec]
    m, n, o = dset.shape        
    index = sorted(np.random.choice(m, size=M, replace=False))

# new code:     
    X = np.empty([M, n-1, o-46, 1])
    for i in range(M):
        ds_arr=dset[index[i],1:,1:256]   
        ds_arr=ds_arr[..., np.newaxis]
        X[i,:,:,:] = ds_arr

# Remove mean & standardize data:
```

Double check my slicing notation carefully. I'm not entirely sure which value you want to remove from the second index (first or last value?). I got a broadcast error when I used `ds_arr=dset[index[i],1:-1,1:256]`. The error message is:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (63,255,1) into shape (64,255,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this was helpful in cleaning up my code and reducing the memory footprint, unfortunately not by enough.  Your code works just fine - I actually gave a wrong initial dimension, n = 66, not 65. Have updated the original post.

Comment: Can you successfully allocate `X` as dimensioned in my code? If so, you need to look in other areas. If not, you need to reduce the size of `M`.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get that working once I corrected the dimensions.  I decided in the end to reduce `M` and `o`.  I was trying not to compromise on that since there is a lot of variance in the types of signals received...but in the end I didn't see a noticeable hit in my AEC performance.  Thanks again for your suggestions!